# Using conditions in pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas

When applying conditions based on value_counts() to an dataframe, a "boolean dataframe" is obtained, as in the example below:

- The csv I am using for the example is [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries).

```
import pandas as pd
sal = pd.read_csv("Salaries.csv")
sal[sal["Year"] == 2013]["JobTitle"].value_counts() == 1
```

Instead of obtaining these booleans, is it possible to filter the dataframe in order to display the actual data of the rows that returned True to the condition?

In the example, the filtered dataframe would have the information (EmployeeName, BasePay, Id...) about each employee that have an unique JobTitle.

Comment: Yes, just use the boolean array/series/dataframe like you would any other to index.

Comment: Do you have an reference link for this? The way I normally do, putting the condition under a bracket, like DF[DF>0] didn't work.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding things, I think `sal[sal.loc[sal["Year"] == 2013, "JobTitle"].value_counts() == 1]` should to the job. _The way I normally do, putting the condition under a bracket, like DF[DF>0] didn't work._ Can you share the exact code you tired?

Comment: Just like you, I tried `sal[sal.loc[sal["Year"] == 2013, "JobTitle"].value_counts() == 1] ` and got an IndexingError.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `transform` with `nunique`

```
targetdf=sal[sal[sal["Year"] == 2013].groupby(["JobTitle"]).transform('nunique')==1].copy()
```

Comment: It worked, you just forgot to use dropna. Thank you!